# ANT build: [signjar] enter passphrase for keystore:

Tags: eclipse, ant, keystore, keytool, jarsigner

I have created a project in eclipse and while trying to build the project from command prompt the following is asked:

```
[signjar] jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: C:\Documents
and Settings\Gopakumar\.keystore (The system cannot find the file specified)


[signjar] Enter Passphrase for keystore:
BUILD FAILED
D:\Score\build.xml:556: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Score\build.xml:147: jarsigner returned: 1
```

I have created keystore file using keytool in the project directory, exactly where build.xml resides.

But it doesn't prompt for the passphrase?

Comment: *"The system cannot find the file specified"* --> Are you sure that the file exists in the exact path `C:\Documents and Settings\Gopakumar\.keystore`? Please double check it.

Comment: No. The keystore file is in the project directory and the path to that keystore file is set in the build.xml. But the system checks for the file in C:\Documents and Settings\Gopakumar\.keystore. Is there any solution to make the system search for it in project directory? I have also tried putting the keystore file in C:\Documents and Settings\Gopakumar\ , but it doesn't worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try it:
Make a StoreFile with "keytool" command:

```
keytool -genkey -keystore YourKeyStoreFileAtPojectDirectory -storepass YourPassStoreString -keyalg rsa -alias YourKeyString -keypass YourPassKeyString -validity 99999  -storepass YourPassStoreString -dname "cn=XXYYZZ, o=XXYYZZ, l=YourCity, S=YourState, c=YourCountry"
```

and put the signjar block below in your build.xml:

```
<signjar destDir="signed" 
  alias="YourKeyString" 
  keypass="YourPassKeyString"
  keystore="YourKeyStoreFileAtPojectDirectory"
  storepass="YourPassStoreString"
  digestalg="SHA1"
  sigalg="MD5withRSA"
>
```